# chart.js - Chart__default.default is not a constructor when used in package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js, package.json, rollup

I am creating a package which includes a react chart component using chart.js

When the package is run in debug in **storybook** it works fine.

However when package is bundled using rollup, referenced in **another project** and the component is used I get the following error:

> Chart__default.default is not a constructor

Not sure if this is relevant but when I debug and insepect the import the Chart var has the file path not an object

[image]

My component:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import Chart, { ChartOptions, ChartData } from 'chart.js/auto'
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker'

const ChartElement: FC = () => {
  const getChartImage = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = 500
    canvas.height = 400
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    if (!ctx) {
      return undefined
    }

    const options: ChartOptions = {
      responsive: false,
      animation: false,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'top' as const
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
        }
      }
    }
    const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July']

    const data:ChartData = {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Dataset 1',
          data: labels.map(() => faker.number.int({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
        },
        {
          label: 'Dataset 2',
          data: labels.map(() => faker.number.int({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
          borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)'
        }
      ]
    }

    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      options,
      data
    })

    // Get the chart's base64 image string
    const image = myChart.toBase64Image()
    console.log(image)
    return image
  }

  const chartImage = getChartImage()

  return (
        <div className='report-element-chart-line'>
          {chartImage &&
            <img src={chartImage}/>
          }
        </div>
  )
}

export default ChartElement
```

Package, tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2016",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017", "dom.iterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "rollup.config.mjs"]
}
```

Package, rollup.config.mjs

```
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import css from 'rollup-plugin-import-css'
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg'

import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' }

export default {
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
      interop: 'compat',
      strict: false,
      libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    sass({ insert: true }),
    typescript({ objectHashIgnoreUnknownHack: true }),
    css(),
    svg()
  ],
  external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react/jsx-runtime']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my import from

```
import Chart, { ChartOptions, ChartData } from 'chart.js/auto'
```

to

```
import Chart, { ChartOptions, ChartData } from '../../node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js'
```

Fixes the issue.